# 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required not working when bean id is changed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting the below exception when in my application. I am using Spring and Hibernate and the dao layer is mostly auto generated by myeclipse.

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
```

The configurations are as below. The auto generated code had bean id's as dataSource, sessionFactory and hibernateTemplate and it was working fine. Then I changed the bean ids to tseDataSource, tseSessionFactory and tseHibernateTemplate. I updated the hibernateTemplate parameter passed to the DAO's accordingly. Then I started getting the above error. When I change these back to dataSource, sessionFactory and hibernateTemplate, the app works fine. But I had to add another datasource, So i have to change these. Is there any reason why this error happens on changing these bean ids.

```
 <bean id="tseDataSource" autowire="byName"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
              value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
    </property>
    <property name="url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://10.4.4.4:3306/tse">
    </property>
    <property name="username" value="tse"></property>
    <property name="password" value="tse"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="tseSessionFactory" autowire="byName"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="tseDataSource" />
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

    </props>

</property>
<property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
    <list>
        <value>Conf/hibernate/tse</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="tseHibernateTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" autowire="byName" >
<property name="sessionFactory">
    <ref local="tseSessionFactory" />
</property>
</bean>


<bean id="tfDataSource" autowire="byName"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName"
          value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
</property>
<property name="url"
          value="jdbc:mysql://10.4.4.4:3306/tf">
</property>
<property name="username" value="tf"></property>
<property name="password" value="tf"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="tfSessionFactory" autowire="byName"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource">
    <ref bean="tfDataSource" />
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>

    </props>

</property>
<property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
    <value>Conf/hibernate/tf</value>
</property>
</bean>
<bean id="tfHibernateTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate" autowire="byName" >
<property name="sessionFactory">
    <ref local="tfSessionFactory" />
</property>
</bean>


<bean id="namesDAO" class="com.NamesDAO"  autowire = "byName" >
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="tfHibernateTemplate"/>
</bean>


<bean id="LogDAO"
      class="com.LogDAO"
      autowire="byName">
<property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="tseHibernateTemplate" />

</bean>
```

Comment: In tseSessionFactory bean definition you have reference to tseDataSource, where is it defined?

Comment: It was in the code but some how didnt show up. I indented at the start of the code and it is now showing.